# How do you merge overlapping .asc files in QGIS with topography and bathymetry?

Tags: qgis, merge, topography, bathymetry

This is my first time trying to manipulate GIS data.

I have two files. The first is higher resolution (SRTM) topography data for a region of islands (the Caribbean), I don't know what the surrounding water values are set to.

The second file has lower resolution topography and bathymetry data over a similar area (ETOPO1).

What I want to do is: combine the two files so that I have the higher resolution topography data (from the first file) surrounded by the lower resolution bathymetry data (from the second file).

Is this possible? If so, how? I have spent ages trying various combinations of merge's, clip's and masks to no avail.

Maybe some further complication are that I only need the higher resolution data for one island of interest, and that the first file has a much larger spatial extent than the second (most of which I don't need due to the single island requirement).

Hopefully that all makes sense, and someone knows how to do what I'm asking.